# How can i divide the window in 4 columns and fill it with images

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to divide this in 4 columns, but this never works. I tried with full height,

```
<style="heigth:100%">
```

in each div and nothing resulted. I could do it with colors, but not with images.

So, how can I divide the window in 4, even when resized and fill it with images?

I have a nav-bar too, but for that I can put it with z-index=1 and make it be visible.

```css
#index1 {
  background: url('img/WhatsApp Image 2022-01-24 at 17.07.09.jpeg');
  position: relative;
}

#index2 {
  background: url('img/WhatsApp Image 2022-01-24 at 17.07.08.jpeg');
  position: relative;
}

#index3 {
  background: url('img/WhatsApp Image 2022-01-24 at 17.07.08(1).jpeg');
  position: relative;
}

#index4 {
  background: url('img/WhatsApp Image 2022-01-24 at 17.07.08(2).jpeg');
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row col-md-12" style="width:100%; height:100%">
  <div class="col-md-3" id="index1"><input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="myFunction1()" value="Calendar" /></div>
  <div class="col-md-3" id="index2"><input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="myFunction2()" value="Classifications" /></div>
  <div class="col-md-3" id="index3"><input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="myFunction3()" value="Winner-Driver" /></div>
  <div class="col-md-3" id="index4"><input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="myFunction4()" value="Winner-Constructor" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up flex layout and alignment using [Bootstrap flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/) classes.

One problem is that your buttons don't fit on smaller screens. You may want to use a vertical stack for mobile and a row for larger screens.

```css
#index1 {
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/800');
}

#index2 {
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/800/dddddd');
}

#index3 {
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/800');
}

#index4 {
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/800/dddddd');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex vw-100 vh-100">
  <div class="w-25 flex-column d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="index1">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="myFunction1()" value="Calendar" />
  </div>

  <div class="w-25 flex-column d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="index2">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="myFunction2()" value="Classifications" />
  </div>

  <div class="w-25 flex-column d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="index3">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="myFunction3()" value="Winner-Driver" />
  </div>

  <div class="w-25 flex-column d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="index4">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="myFunction4()" value="Winner-Constructor" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, about the larger and smaller devices i will see that better, since if i use rows for larger screens i would need to change the images because i chosed this images exactly for vertical columns.

Answer (score 0):

By default any `<div>` has a height=0. It can expand if there is an element inside the div. But it will not expand with the size of background-image of the `<div>`.

Your code is perfect except that you have not specified height in the corresponding `<div>` elements. You have to specify height to each div containing a background. Otherwise the browser will make it's height=0 or in this case the height of the button.

Height='100%' does not work in your case because the row height will be calculated to 100% to it's largest child element (Not the browser window!). That is the div -> which is the height of it's child element button.

The height must be specified in either px, em, rem, vh. Height does not behave like width!

---

Easiest solution: Set row height to 100vh instead of 100%

---

If you want to set height of each div, you can do it by adding height or min-height property to them. Try experimenting with different values. 
**Tip: You can check your div size by going to code inspector of browser (in windows: right mouse click and inspect)

---

```
<style>
    #index1 {
      background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?fire');
      position: relative;
      height: 90vh; //Experiment here
    }

    #index2 {
      background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?beach');
      position: relative;
      height: 500px; //Experiment here
    }

    #index3 {
      background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?team');
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100vh; //Experiment here
    }

    #index4 {
      background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?love');
      position: relative;
      min-height: 50vh; //Experiment here
    }
  </style>
```

Html:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-3" id="index1"><input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="myFunction1()"
          value="Calendar" /></div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="index2"><input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="myFunction2()"
          value="Classifications" /></div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="index3"><input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="myFunction3()"
          value="Winner-Driver" /></div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="index4"><input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="myFunction4()"
          value="Winner-Constructor" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

*Remember: The row will always have a height of the largest child element here.

I hope this guideline will help you in this project and all your future projects. All the best.

Comment: Thx, nice explanation ( it helps a lot to understand ).